# Almost isometric linear maps

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Say that a linear map $\varphi : B(\mathcal H) \rightarrow B(\mathcal H)$ is $\epsilon$-almost isometric if
$$ 1 - \epsilon \leq \lVert\varphi(a)\rVert \leq 1+\epsilon, \quad \forall a\in B(\mathcal H), \text{s.t. }\lVert a\rVert=1,  $$
where $B(\mathcal H)$ denotes the set of bounded operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Does there exist a constant $C$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ and every $\epsilon$-almost isometric linear map $\phi$, there exists an isometric linear map $\psi : B(\mathcal H) \rightarrow B(\mathcal H)$ such that $\lVert\varphi - \psi\rVert < C\epsilon$?

If that is too hard or false, what about in finite dimension?

Comment: I don't quite understand  the definition of "almost isometric linear map".  Is $\phi$ assumed linear or not? If yes, dividing by $M>0$ all terms of the inequality applied to $Ma$, by the homogeneity of $\phi$  one gets the same inequality with $\epsilon/M$ instead of $\epsilon$, so that letting $M\to+\infty$, $\|\phi(a)\|=\|a\|$ for all $a$, and $\phi$ is already a linear isometry. If $\phi$ is not assumed linear, then e.g. $\phi(a):=\pm a$ with a random sign satisfies the inequality and certainly is not close to a linear isometry.

Comment: Excellent comments, I will change that.

Comment: Maybe you mean $ \|a\|(1-\epsilon)\le\varphi(a)\le\|a\|(1+\epsilon)$ ?

Comment: I still don't see whether or not $\varphi$ is assumed to be linear.

Comment: You probably mean that "there exists an $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ such that...", right? Otherwise, every bounded linear operator is "almost isometric".

Comment: @WlodAA Yes it is a linear map as the question states.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I'm ok living in a world where everything is "almost isometric" ;) What really matters is if there is some universal constant C or at least some non-trivial function depending on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Chris "Yes it is a linear map as the question states". No, your question doesn't state it. The question makes an impression that there is no assumption about $\ \varphi\ $ being linear.

Comment: @WlodAA But it's the third word in the title and the sixth word in the question. It would be better English for me to have written "almost isometric, linear map".

Comment: Can this statement hold for all Banach spaces (perhaps for invertible $\varphi$ only)? In the answer it is proven for Hilbert spaces, which does not say much since there is many isometries on a Hilbert space, but that's a start. Or perhaps to the contrary, can this be a characterization of having a lot of isometries?

Comment: You've probably already looked at this, Chris, but is there some extra juice to be squeezed from Kadison's original paper on isometries between C*-algebras? Those results are usually stated for surjective isometries but some of the lemmas have info about e.g. extreme points of unit ball of B(H)

Comment: Also: if you're prepared to weaken $C\epsilon$ to "continuous function of $\epsilon$ which vanishes at zero" then *maybe* one could try to run an ultraproduct argument? Jarosz has exploited this in some old work which boosts isometric results to "almost implies near" results

Answer (score 7):

The answer is yes if you assume $\varphi$ is surjective, and you're only looking for a function $f(\epsilon)$ which tends to zero as $\epsilon$ tends to zero.

Let's call a function $\varphi$ satisfying your given condition an *$\epsilon$-isometric*, linear map.

**Theorem**: For every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $\mathcal{H}$ and every linear, surjective, $\delta$-isometric map $\varphi : B(\mathcal{H})\to B(\mathcal{H})$, there is a linear isometry $\psi : B(\mathcal{H})\to B(\mathcal{H})$ such that $\|\varphi - \psi\| \le \epsilon$.

**Proof**: Suppose otherwise and fix $1/k$-isometric, linear, surjective maps $\varphi_k : B(\mathcal{H}_k)\to B(\mathcal{H}_k)$ which remain $\epsilon$-far away from any isometry.  Then we may define a map
$$ \Phi : \prod B(\mathcal{H}_k) / \bigoplus B(\mathcal{H}_k) \to \prod B(\mathcal{H}_k) / \bigoplus B(\mathcal{H}_k) $$
in the obvious way.  Note that $\Phi$ is surjective, linear and isometric.  By a [theorem of Kadison](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969534?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), then, $\Phi$ has the form $\Phi(x) = u \rho(x)$, where $u$ is a unitary and $\rho$ is a Jordan $^*$-isomorphism.  (Recall that a Jordan $^*$-isomorphism is a linear, $^*$-preserving map $\rho$ satisfying $\rho(ab + ba) = \rho(a)\rho(b) + \rho(b)\rho(a)$.)  We may find unitaries $U_k\in B(\mathcal{H_k})$ such that the sequence $(U_k)$ represents $u$.  Then, multiplying by $u^*$ on the left, we may assume that $\Phi = \rho$.  Then $\varphi_k$ is an $\epsilon_k$-approximate Jordan $^*$-isomorphism in the sense that
$$ \| \varphi_k(ab + ba) - \varphi_k(a)\varphi_k(b) - \varphi_k(b)\varphi_k(a)\| \le \epsilon_k \|a\|\|b\| $$
where $\epsilon_k\to 0$.  By a result of [Ilišević and Turnšek](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03081087.2015.1028169), there is an actual Jordan $^*$-isomorphism $\psi_k : B(\mathcal{H}_k)\to B(\mathcal{H}_k)$ such that $\|\psi_k - \varphi_k\|\to 0$, and since Jordan $^*$-isomorphisms are isometries, this is a contradiction.

Comment: This is a nice argument. Ultimately, for me, it would be great to get some bound on the convergence when one is only dealing with finite-dimensional C*-algebras.

Comment: The result of Ilišević and Turnšek that I mentioned has an explicit bound that looks like $K\epsilon^{1/2} (1 + o(1))$.  You might be able to construct a function $g$ such that every $\epsilon$-isometric, linear surjection is a $g(\epsilon)$-approximate Jordan $^*$-isomorphism, but that would probably involve following through the proof of Kadison's theorem.

Comment: Also, note that the function $f$ above is uniform over the dimension of $H$, so it's got that going for it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a version of this question that gives specific bounds at the cost of more conditions.

Theorem 3.4 in [Erik Christensen, "Perturbations of operator algebras", Invent. Math. 43 (1977), 1-13.](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/30846855.pdf)

Let $\Phi$ be a surjective completely positive linear map between $B(H_1)$ and $B(H_2)$ (the algebras can be more general than this). If $t \in [0,1/84]$ such that
$\|\Phi\| \leq 1$ and $\|\Phi^{-1}\| \leq 1 + t$, then there exists a $*$-isomorphism $\Psi$ such that
$$\| \Phi -\Psi\| \leq 8.5\sqrt t + 7t$$

Answer (score -1):

By the [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition#Bounded_operators_on_Hilbert_space) we have $\phi = AU$ for some positive-semidefinite self-adjoint $A$ and some partial isometry $U$. Since $\phi$ has no kernel $U$ must be a (not necessarily surjective) isometry. Note that $A$ also satisfies the hypothesis $1-\epsilon \leq \|Ax\| \leq 1 + \epsilon$ for $\|x\|=1$. We claim that $\|A - I\| \leq \epsilon$. This follows from the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Multiplication_operator_version), though presumably there is also a more elementary proof.

Comment: Note that the operator $\phi$ in the question is *not* an operator on $\mathcal{H}$ but on $B(\mathcal{H})$. Thus, there is no polar decomposition for $\phi$, in general.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I overlooked that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Anyway, I'm still interested in your answer for operators $\phi$ on Hilbert spaces. In case that $U$ is not surjective, how do you obtain the estimate for $\|Ax\|$?

Comment: I should have said that estimate holds for all $x \in \operatorname{im} U$ such that $\|x\|=1$, and then it follows that $\|A|_U - I|_U\|\leq \epsilon$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thanks for the response but ultimately this won't lead to an answer to my question for the reasons pointed out.